# Show custom error on lightning:input

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system

I was trying if we can validate input in javascript and then post errors on latest **lightning:input**. But i think it doesn't support such use case.

pattern attribute is there but it cant work when i/p is based on other fields.

The requirement I am trying to achieve is that phone number without spaces should be 11 digits.

Markup:

```
          <lightning:input type="tel" label="Telephone"
             name="tel" value="{!v.applicant1.Phone__c}" pattern="^[0-9_ ]*$"
             messageWhenPatternMismatch="Phone number is not valid"
             onblur='{!c.checkValidityOfphone}'
             messageWhenBadInput='Phone number should be 11 chars max'
             />
```

Controller:

```
checkValidityOfphone : function(component, event, helper) {
  console.log('checkValidityOfphone called');
  var inp = event.getSource();
  var val=inp.get('v.value');
  val=val.replace(/ /g,'');
  console.log(val);
  console.log(val.length);
  if(val.length!=11){
    inp.set("v.errors", [{message:"Input not a number: " + val}]);
    console.log('Error Set called');   
    //  inp.get('v.validity').valid=false;
  }
}
```

According to the given doc, lightning:input does support client side validations.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_validate_fields.htm

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a bit of an old question now, but I've discovered another way which seems pretty legit. The validity attribute of lightning:input is not just for reading the validity, you can also set it. So, write the component like this:

```
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.value}" action="{!c.valueChangeValidation}"/>

<lightning:input aura:id="inputField" 
                 type="text" value="{!v.value}" 
                 label="Enter foo" 
                 messageWhenBadInput="You must say foo" />
```

And then the controller like this:

```
valueChangeValidation : function(component, event, helper) {
    var inputField = component.find('inputField');
    var value = inputField.get('v.value');
    if(value != 'foo') {
        inputField.set('v.validity', {valid:false, badInput :true});
        inputField.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();

    }
}
```

Then, you can write whatever logic you want in that handler method and the result is shown in the normal Lightning way.

Comment: Does the solution presented here work still? I'm trying to do some custom validation and this isn't working for me.

Comment: Hi @ratatoskr , you have to call   'inputField.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();' after setting the valid flag as false. This displays error message. I have edited the answer to reflect the same

Comment: Thanks @PranayJaiswal, though I've tried that and still nothing. Is this working in Spring '18 orgs?

Comment: I tried in summer 18, works charm. Would try again on Spring 18 and confirm

Comment: Ah, I suppose I meant Summer, but in any case still very frustrating because I've copied exactly what you have here and still nothing. I can see valid: true and badInput: false on a console.dir of the inputField. Time to go custom, I guess.

Comment: This is not working anymore. From [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/documentation): "This validity attribute is a read-only object with the following boolean properties."

Comment: @DanielHorký is right, this no longer works, but they gave us something very similar: reasonCmp.setCustomValidity("Error message or blank if valid"); reasonCmp.reportValidity();

Comment: `reportValidity()` does not clear error when component is valid. I think it's bug.

Comment: you need to set the customValidity to blank to clear the message - setCustomValidity("") and call reportValidity().

Answer (score 5):

I noticed a few issues:

- `v.errors` is not available in `lightning:input` though it's available in `ui:input`. So you'll want to define the errors attribute in your component and iterate over it to display the errors.
- `event.getSource().get('v.value')` won't give you the input value here. You can use `component.find("tel").get("v.value")` instead.

Here's the revised code (I removed `value="{!v.applicant1.Phone__c}` when testing in my org):

```
<aura:component >
<aura:attribute name="errors" type="List"/>
<lightning:input aura:id="tel" type="tel" label="Telephone"
         name="tel"  pattern="^[0-9_ ]*$"
         messageWhenPatternMismatch="Phone number is not valid"
         onblur='{!c.checkValidityOfphone}'
         messageWhenBadInput='Phone number should be 11 chars max'
         /> 
<aura:iteration items="{!v.errors}" var="error">{!errors}</aura:iteration>
```

```
({
    checkValidityOfphone : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('checkValidityOfphone called');
        //var inp = event.getSource();
        var val=component.find("tel").get('v.value');
        val=val.replace(/ /g,'');
        console.log(val);
        console.log(val.length);
        if(val.length!=11){
            component.set("v.errors", ["Input not a number: " + val]);
            console.log('Error Set called');   
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a new method on `lightning:input` named `reportValidity()` that simplifies validation. The docs describe this method as doing the following:

> If the input is invalid, displays the error and returns false. If the input is valid, clears any displayed error and returns true.

Here's a link to the full documentation and you should look for the Input Validation section: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/documentation

Here's an example of how to use this:

```
const inputField = component.find('input-field-aura-id');
if(inputField.reportValidity()) {
    component.set('v.attributeName', inputField.get('v.value'));
}
```

I suggest using `reportValidity()` because it does all the work for you. The other way to do this (described in other answers) is to get a component's `validity` attribute, check if the `valid` property is true and if it is, calling `showHelpMessageIfInvalid()` to display an error message.

Comment: From the docs: 
This component supports the following methods.
focus(): Sets focus on the element.
setCustomValidity(): Sets the custom error message.
**reportValidity():** If the input is invalid, displays the error and returns false. If the input is valid, clears any displayed error and returns true.
checkValidity(): Returns true if the input is valid.

Comment: sweet, thanks for updating you answer =)  +1

Answer (score 2):

As of API v39.0, checking validity in `lightning:input` got a lot easier. Here's my controller:

```
({
    checkValidity : function(component, event, helper) {
        var validity = event.getSource().get("v.validity");
        console.log(validity)
    }
})
```

and here's my component:

```
<aura:component >
    <lightning:input aura:id="tel" type="tel" label="Telephone"
                     name="tel"  pattern="^[0-9_ ]*$" maxlength="11"
                     messageWhenPatternMismatch="Phone number is not valid"
                     onblur='{!c.checkValidity}'
                     /> 
</aura:component>
```

All you have to do is check the validity attribute of your `lightning:input`, and your configured error messages will appear below it automatically.

Comment: Note, Diana's answer is correct if you wanted to bring your own validation instead of use the default pattern/maxlength validation by attribute.

Comment: But your answer perfectly suits to Present scenaio...

Answer (score 1):

I played around with Aidan's accepted answer but couldn't get the showHelpMessageIfInvalid() method to behave reliably. In my case, for some reason it would only show the error message *after* a user had entered their value, then tabbed off the field *THEN* came back to the field I was validating and attempted to tab back off again.

I did a quick debug and the validation method was firing on first input...but the error text wasn't showing up. Very frustrating. After beating my head against the proverbial SF wall, I ended up going with a completely custom route. It's a bit more work, but it's pretty reliable and arguably more flexible than the built-in SF method.

The basic idea is to have a lightning:input field and associated a lightning:formattedText field with it via aura:id. This formattedText has a css class that hides it (display:none). When the input field is filled out, onblur throws event, which you can capture. The controller captures the field that threw the event (not shown in code, but I have five or six fields that have this same validation, so I generalized it a bit). Then run your own custom validation. If the validation fails, add a "show" css class which sets the display to flex, showing the error message. Relevant code below:

Component:

```
<div class="slds-col slds-size_4-of-12">
                <lightning:input type="number" label="FTE" aura:id="genFTE1" step="0.01"
                                 onblur="{!c.validateFTE}"/>
                <p><lightning:formattedText aura:id="fteError" class="error-text" value="Value must be between 0 and .49" /></p>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
validateFTE : function(component, event, helper) {
        //Get field that triggered the event
        var field = component.find(event.getSource().getLocalId());
        //Get value of field
        var val = field.get("v.value");
        //Validate entry and show error message if validation is not passed
        if(val < 0 || val > 0.49) {
            $A.util.addClass(component.find("fteError"),"show");
        } else {
            $A.util.removeClass(component.find("fteError"), "show");
        }
    }
```

CSS:

```
.THIS .error-text {
    display:none;
}

.THIS .show {
    display:flex;
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there's actually a spec for U.S. phone numbers called [NANP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Numbering_Plan).

So if you're looking for a more comprehensive phone number validation, you could use the following regex, which checks for stuff like extensions.  The component below is based on a regex I found on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation).

```
<lightning:input 
    type="tel" 
    value="{!v.someValue}" 
    aura:id="mobile" 
    name="mobile" 
    readonly="{!v.readOnly}" 
    label="Cellular Telephone Number" 
    messageWhenPatternMismatch="Please specify a valid phone format such as (###)-###-#### ext ###" 
    pattern="^(?:(?:\+?1\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})(?:\s*(?:#|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?$"/>
```